# Python File Concatenation

Tags: python, file, logging, concatenation

I have a data folder, with subfolders for each subject that ran through a program. So, for example, in the data folder, there are folders for Bob, Fred, and Tom. Each one of those folders contains a variety of files and subfolders. However, I am only interested in the 'summary.log' file contained in each subject's folder.

I want to concatenate the 'summary.log' file from Bob, Fred, and Tom into a single log file in the data folder. In addition, I want to add a column to each log file that will list the subject number.

Is this possible to do in Python? Or is there an easier way to do it? I have tried a number of different batches of code, but none of them get the job done. For example,

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys, string, glob, os

fls = glob.glob(r'/Users/slevclab/Desktop/Acceptability Judgement Task/data/*');
outfile = open('summary.log','w');
for x in fls:
         file=open(x,'r');
         data=file.read();
         file.close();
         outfile.write(data);
outfile.close();
```

Gives me the error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fileconcat.py", line 8, in <module>
    file=open(x,'r');
IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory
```

I think this has to do with the fact that the data folder contains subfolders, but I don't know how to work around it. I also tried this, but to no avail:

```
from glob import iglob
import shutil
import os

PATH = r'/Users/slevclab/Desktop/Acceptability Judgement Task/data/*'

destination = open('summary.log', 'wb')
for filename in iglob(os.path.join(PATH, '*.log'))
    shutil.copyfileobj(open(filename, 'rb'), destination)
destination.close()
```

This gives me an "invalid syntax" error at the "for filename" line, but I'm not sure what to change.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is not related to the use of glob.
You forget the ":" at the end of the for statement:

```
for filename in iglob(os.path.join(PATH, '*.log')):
                                                  ^--- missing
```

But the following pattern works :

```
PATH = r'/Users/slevclab/Desktop/Acceptability Judgement Task/data/*/*.log'

destination = open('summary.log', 'wb')
for filename in iglob(PATH):
    shutil.copyfileobj(open(filename, 'rb'), destination)
destination.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The colon (`:`) is missing in the `for` line.
Besides you should use `with` because it handles closing the file (your code is not exception safe).

```
from glob import iglob
import shutil
import os

PATH = r'/Users/slevclab/Desktop/Acceptability Judgement Task/data/*'

with open('summary.log', 'wb') as destination:
    for filename in iglob(os.path.join(PATH, '*.log')):
        with open(filename, 'rb') as in_:
            shutil.copyfileobj(in_, destination)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first example:

```
import sys, string, glob, os
```

you are not using `sys`, `string` or `os`, so there is no need to import those.

```
fls = glob.glob(r'/Users/slevclab/Desktop/Acceptability Judgement Task/data/*');
```

here, you are selecting the *subject folders*.  Since you are interested in `summary.log` files within these folders, you may change the pattern as follows:

```
fls = glob.glob('/Users/slevclab/Desktop/Acceptability Judgement Task/data/*/summary.log')
```

In Python, there is no need to end lines with semicolons.

```
outfile = open('summary.log','w')
for x in fls:
     file = open(x, 'r')
     data = file.read()
     file.close()
     outfile.write(data)
outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

As [VGE's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831780/python-file-concatenation/6831829#6831829) shows, your second solution works once you've fixed the syntax error. But note that a more general solution is to use `os.walk`:

```
>>> import os
>>> for i in os.walk('foo'):
...     print i
... 
('foo', ['bar', 'baz'], ['oof.txt'])
('foo/bar', [], ['rab.txt'])
('foo/baz', [], ['zab.txt'])
```

This goes through all the directories in the tree above the start directory and maintains a nice separation between directories and files.